# Display cartthrob subtotal + tax + discount - shipping

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, tags

On my shopping cart page I'd like to display the total (inc tax & discounts!) but not including shipping costs. I can't find a tag for this unless I'm missing something.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but I'm assuming the {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal_minus_discount} tag doesn't include the tax?  Perhaps then it would be best to calculate the {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal_minus_discount} + {exp:cartthrob:cart_tax} values using javascript or an EE math plugin like one of these:

- [EE Math Plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math)
- [MX Calculator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator)

Comment: Looks like CT has an arithmetic tag.. http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/arithmetic/index.html

Comment: Even better!  It's always good to avoid installing extraneous plugins whenever possible, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating a partial (includes/cart_subtitle.html):

```
{!-- Calculate total without delivery --}
{exp:cartthrob:arithmetic expression="({embed:subtotal} - {embed:discount}) + {embed:tax}"}
```

and in the main template:

```
{embed="includes/cart_subtotal" discount="{exp:cartthrob:cart_discount prefix="" thousands_sep=""}" tax="{exp:cartthrob:cart_tax prefix="" thousands_sep=""}" subtotal="{exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix="" thousands_sep=""}" }
```

Bit ugly, but it works :)